# mxmlc compiles differently under linux and windows?

Tags: windows, linux, apache-flex

I have a project which has several components loaded by a single preloader swf.

The preloader swf is strictly AS3 (No flex) and uses Loaders to load two different swfs which both use the flex library (Statically compiled, not rsl).

When I compile all three under linux and run the resulting preloader, one of the swfs fails to load properly, and the exception below (at the bottom of this post) is thrown.

If I compile the same component using the same ant task in windows, the component loads just fine without error. The windows file is also 683 bytes smaller.

This is true using the flex SDK 3.2.0 and 3.3.0 under linux and windows.

Have you seen this type of behavior? Can you offer any suggestions for why it might be happening, or how to determine what is wrong?

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.managers::FocusManager/activate()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/activateForm()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/activate()
at mx.core::Application/initManagers()
at mx.core::Application/initialize()
at OC_Footer/initialize()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::childAdded()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::docFrameHandler()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/docFrameListener()
```

Comment: If you figure it out, I suggest filing a bug with Adobe: http://bugs.adobe.com/flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've solved the real problem (Why the compilation was different under different OS's), but I have found that the newer version of the flex SDK does *not* exhibit the same issues.

I created a bug for the issue here:

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-20147

The short of it is, build 3958 (The one default with flexbuilder at the time that I created the bug -- This may still be true)  appears to have a number of minor bugs. Upgrading the flex SDK to build 4852 alleviates the symptoms, and I can build projects successfully in a number of environments.

Answer (score 0):

So wait, are you using different version of the SDK in each platform? That would certainly account for some differences (at the very least in the size of the swf...)

IIUC you get this error when you're loading the page in the browser, right? It's hard to tell from just the stack trace what's wrong, but I can tell you that I used to get a similar error on Windows and it had to do with keyboard events (e.g. using the tab key to move between elements when popups are visible, and similar stuff). Sorry I can't offer a more accurate diagnosis.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, same sdk version on linux and windows.

Also, it works properly, no errors whatsoever when this component is compiled on windows.

Comment: Also to be clear, all three components are initially compiled on the linux box. One of them doesn't load. Taking the other two from the linux box, and adding the third from the windows box, allows the whole framework to function.